# Unable Create any SharedPreferences

Tags: android

I usually use this code for creating sharedPrefs file:

```
SharedPrefrences SP = getSharedPrefrences("MYPREF",0);
SP.getString("Username","x");
```

But now if I see this directory:

```
"/data/data/packageName/"
```

There is no shared_prefs directory.

*Another thing :* if I use Editor its work properly.

Comment: i want to do it but this message shown :"once you earn 15....". totaly ILoveYou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to `SET` the data with an `Editor`

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("Name","Pepito");
editor.apply();
```

Then you can read it as follows :

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String name = preferences.getString("Name", "Here's the default value");
```

If you've set the value after make that `getString()` your `String` value will be `"Pepito"`, otherwise you'll get `"Here's the default value"`

Answer (score 4):

First you need to store some data in shared preferences using apply()/commit() method so that you retrieve data from there.

```
    SharedPrefrences SP = getSharedPrefrences("MYPREF",0);
    SP.edit().putString("Username","SOME NAME").apply();
    System.out.println("Username is : "+SP.getString("Username","x"));
```

Comment: if i want to use default values what i most do ?

Comment: the "x" you have passed is the default value. In place of x you can pass any string